# Audio distorted on pulse/alsa, works fine on JACK. How to analyze why JACK works correctly and use that knowledge to fix pulse/alsa configuration?

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

To test and resolve this problem I am using a fresh install of Fedora 33, audio settings or configuration files left untouched.

By default the audio is heavily distorted (it *is* possible to make out what is being played, but overall it is not usable).

However when I install and start `jackd` and leave it running with the following settings:

```
jackd -r -dalsa -dhw:0 -r48000 -p256 -n2
```

and then try an audio file with `mpv` (which is able to use JACK), the sound is crisp and clear, *working as intended*:

```
mpv --ao=jack test.flac
```

Note: `jackd` with `-r44100` works too.

This is of course not a satisfying general approach because not every software is able to use JACK by itself, so it doesn't work with Firefox, for example.

Because JACK is able to handle things properly, I guess that either the pulse or alsa (automatic) settings are causing the problem? Or could it be something else?

**In short:** How can I replicate what JACK does using an ALSA configuration (or pulseaudio for that matter). A solution through ALSA would be *preferred* to make this answer work *without pulse* as well. It is of course also possible that pulseuadio is the part is causing the problem, I do not know.

---

**Additional information:**

- Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Studio [Audiofuse Studio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

- Output of `jackd -r -dalsa -dhw:0 -r48000 -p256 -n2`:

```
jackdmp 1.9.14
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2019 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|256|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 256 frames (5.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
```

- Output of `aplay --dump-hw-params -D hw:Studio -t raw /dev/zero`:

```
Playing raw data '/dev/zero' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
HW Params of device "hw:Studio":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S32_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: [320 576]
CHANNELS: [10 18]
RATE: [44100 192000]
PERIOD_TIME: [125 297211)
PERIOD_SIZE: [6 13107]
PERIOD_BYTES: [240 524288]
PERIODS: [2 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: (62 594422)
BUFFER_SIZE: [12 26214]
BUFFER_BYTES: [480 1048576]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
aplay: set_params:1343: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

- Output of `cat /proc/asound/Studio/stream0` (only "Playback"):

```
Playback:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S32_LE
    Channels: 18
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000
    Data packet interval: 125 us
    Bits: 24
  Interface 1
    Altset 2
    Format: S32_LE
    Channels: 18
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000
    Data packet interval: 125 us
    Bits: 24
  Interface 1
    Altset 3
    Format: S32_LE
    Channels: 10
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000
    Data packet interval: 125 us
    Bits: 24
    Channel map: FL FR FC LFE RL RR FLC FRC RC SL
```

Comment: FYI, Jack also uses the ALSA drivers, so it can't be that. To simplify, keep Pulseaudio out of the picture. From your information, Jack uses 48 kHz, so try ALSA playback (`aplay`) with 48 kHz as well - if ALSA uses a different bit rate by default, this is the first thing to check.

Comment: Since it works with JACK, and JACK uses ALSA in my case, we know that ALSA is capable of using the Audio Interface correctly. But at the same time it (and/or pulse) are also *causing* the problem by setting the config wrong somehow? This is my assumption.

As you recommended I tried aplay. To make sure I turned off `pulseaudio` by doing `echo "autospawn = no" > .config/pulse/client.conf` and `pulseaudio --kill`. Confirmed with `pulseaudio --check` that it is not running.

Then tested with `aplay --rate=48000 test.wav`, but the sound is still distorted, I also tried `mpv --ao=alsa test.wav`

Comment: I also have to add that `pulseaudio --check` reports that it is running again immediately after using `aplay`. So I don't think my way of "turning off pulsaudio" worked here. When I kill pulseaudio with `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket` and `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service`, aplay does not work anymore and gives an error: `ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused`.

*In this state it is however still possible to start `jackd` and have audio work normally and clear through it, as described in my question.*

Comment: `aplay` uses the `pulse` device by default as a compatibility layer. So you need `aplay -D hw:0 ...` (if the order of cards stays like in your `aplay -l` output). If you cannot access `hw:0` directly, then some other application is claiming it, for example Pulseaudio (which apparently respawns on your system). So not sure if your `aplay` attempt used the restarted Pulseaudio, or not; better try again to confirm you are really using the hardware directly.

Comment: When I try `aplay -D hw:0 test.wav` I get the error `aplay: set_params:1343: Sample format non available` `Available formats: - S32_LE` (I checked that the card order stayed the same).

Due to the nature of the error I also tried `aplay -f S32_LE -D hw:0 test.wav` but this results in the exact same error message.

Comment: Ok, so your card is at least somewhat picky. You need a WAV with 32 bit samples to test. If you can't make one, try `aplay --dump-hw-params -D hw:0 -t raw /dev/zero` and edit question with output. This is not as exact as giving it the right format, but if there's no 44.1 kHz, at least it's a clue. For actual testing you will need a WAV file in the right format, though.

Comment: I was able to obtain one, trying `aplay -D hw:Studio 32bit-test.wav` I get basically the same error message:

`Playing WAVE '32bit-test.wav' : Float 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo` `aplay: set_params:1343: Sample format non available` `Available formats: - S32_LE`. I added the outputs of `aplay --dump-hw-params -D hw:Studio -t raw /dev/zero` as well as the output of `cat /proc/asound/Studio/stream0` to the question, in case that helps :)

Comment: That's float. Use something to convert the formats, e.g. `sox`. How exactly is the audio distorted? Is there a pitch change ("squeaky voice"), or something else? Format mismatch due to a driver bug would mean the latter, frequency mismatch the former.

Comment: I see, I tried converting the file myself using `sox`.  What I got then was the following error: `Playing WAVE 'CONVERTED-test.wav' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo` `aplay: set_params:1349: Channels count non available`. Using `channels 18` with the sox command then finally makes `aplay` play the file properly and clear! **Note**: When I convert the file using sox with `channels 10` the file is played by aplay too, however in that case the file is again distorted. Any other number for `channels` will result in the `channels count non available` error.

Comment: When it comes to describing the type of distortion: It does not appear pitch shifted, but rather "crushed" and also muffled, I would say. Thank you for the patience so far, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see, I tried converting the file myself using sox. What I got then was the following error: Playing WAVE 'CONVERTED-test.wav' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo aplay: set_params:1349: Channels count non available. Using channels 18 with the sox command then finally makes aplay play the file properly and clear! Note: When I convert the file using sox with channels 10 the file is played by aplay too, however in that case the file is again distorted. Any other number for channels will result in the channels count non available error.

So it looks like the interface with 10 channels has a bug in the driver or somewhere else, and you need to convince Pulseaudio to use the interface with 18 channels.

Looking at [module-alsa-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-alsa-sink), you can put it an ALSA device.

Which probably means you need to do the configuration in `~/.asoundrc`.

You configure the number of channels in the [hw plugin](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html), but I've never done this myself, and I don't have hardware with those channel choices.

So I guess this will need some experimentation with the various configuration files. This is hard to do remotely, and I cannot give you step-by-step instructions.

Another option would be to file a bugreport on the ALSA tracker. They might find out the problem in the driver (which probably needs a quirk, if it's the generic USB driver), or give you advice how the configuration files would look like.

ALSA Bug tracking is explained [here](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Bug_Tracking).

Comment: So I looked at the interface manual which shows the USB Audio mapping, which changes based on the sampling rate: 18 out is for 44.1/48 kHz and 88.2/96 kHz (input number changes). The 10 out channel mapping is meant for 176.4/192 kHz. I tried setting the s. rate to 192 kHz in asound.conf, and it worked! For programs that use pulse setting the default-sample-rate to 192 kHz in pulse/daemon.conf works too! So this makes it all behave, thanks a lot for your insight!
Only remaining: Is there is a way to make linux choose one of the other mappings (in stream0 referred to as "Altset"?), any ideas?

Comment: I've never come across any hardware that has "Altsets", so I do not know. If I had, I probably would now be reading the driver code source to find out (and I'd probably need to spend quite a bit time on that).